# How to aggregate JSF 1.2 applications into Liferay Portlet

Tags: liferay, jsf-1.2

Currently I have a JSF 1.2 project, and I want to use it in Liferay portlet.

Since it is a big project, it is impossible to upgrade to JSF 2.x within a short time.

From https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+Faces+Version+Scheme, it is possible to use JSF 1.2 in Liferay portlet if:
- Liferay Faces Version is 2.1.x
- Liferay Portal Version is 6.1.x

How can I exactly use it? If I follow the Developer's Guide, http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-a-portl-3, it creates Portlet for JSF 2.x, not for JSF 1.2.

I am wondering if there is a way to create a Liferay Portel for JSF 1.2?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [follow these instructions](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Building+Liferay+Faces+From+Source), but checkout 2.1.3-ga4 instead, you will find portlets in the demos directory such as the jsf1-portlet and many others:

demos/bridge/jsf1-portlet/target/jsf1-portlet-2.1.3-ga4.war

All of the portlets you will find in the demos directory are working examples which use jsf 1.2.  You can then deploy those to your favorite Liferay Portal, version 6.1, add one of those portlets to a page and try it out.

All of the demo portlets come with their source code in the git repo.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replying. Is there a tutorial that creating a Liferay Portlet for JSF 1.2 from scratch?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such tutorial that I know of that shows how to use the latest versions of the bridge, and there is not likely to be one soon for JSF 1.2.  Any new tutorials will likely be about JSF 2.2.

The basics steps are: 
1. start with a (simple?) JSF application. 
2. add the five Liferay Faces jars ... Bridge(2), Alloy, Portal, util. 
3. add three xml files such as those listed in the WEB-INF dir of the demos: liferay-display.xml, liferay-portlet.xml, portlet.xml (since you already have a faces-config.xml and a web.xml). Is this big project you mentioned using jsp views?